# Create directive to use across models and controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have very similar functionality throughout my app whereby a user can input a title and link.

So - I thought I'd create a directive. However, this directive will need to be used in the context of various controllers.

For example - in my /contracts view, the controller is ContractsController, and on submit, the ContractsController will send an API request to save a contract.

But in my /meeting-notes view, the controller is MeetingNotesController, and this will handle a request to a different endpoint - to save meeting notes against a client.

Here's my directive so far:
**app.js**

```
.directive('myprefixLinkAttachment', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: '../partials/directives/link-attachment.html',
        scope: {},
        link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(function() {
                console.log(scope.$parent);
                console.log(scope.title);
            }, 5000);
        }
    }
})
```

The timeout returns the correct value - I was testing to see if I could get the value.

**link-attachment.html**

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" md-no-float flex="100" flex-gt-xs="66">

    <input ng-model="title" placeholder="Title...">

</md-input-container>

<md-input-container class="md-block" flex="100" flex-gt-xs="33">

    <input ng-model="link" placeholder="Title..." ng-keypress="CtrlNameHere.save($event)">

</md-input-container>
```

And I call the directive from inside (in this example) the **ContractsController** - but this will need to vary.

```
<div layout="column" layout-gt-xs="row" class="new-entry-line" myprefix-link-attachment>
```

In summary - I'd like to use the directive freely, whilst being able to call the correct controller to handle the CtrlNameHere.save() method.

Comment: Did you try to pass save method to directive?

Comment: How would it know which controller to pass it to? I guess I could use $parent but I've read that's not advised?

Comment: you can create a service to synchronize the data

Answer (score 1):

You haven't asked a question.
I presume what you mean to ask is how to call a function of controller when you use the same directive in scopes of different controllers.

What you need to do is to pass the directive the function it will call.

So in you directive you need to accept a controllerFn property, like so:

```
scope: {
    controllerFn: "="
}
```

when using directive, pass it the function of the controller, like so:

```
<myprefix-link-attachment controller-fn="someControllerFunction">
```

finally in template, call the function you already have in scope:

```
ng-keypress="controllerFn($event)"
```

Comment: controllerFn needs to be set as reference property, e.g.:
`scope: {controllerFn: '&'}`. Also it's a good practice to set appropriate name for component properties, like 'on-save' since it could be used across whole app not only within controller.

Comment: @VasylRomanchak is correct, it needs to be set as a reference property. Issue now is $event is not passed to my controller - and how do I get the title/link values in the controller in order to save them?